# How do I know if I have Windows administrator rights from command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

How do I know if I have Windows administrator rights from command line? Particularly on **Windows7**?

Is there any equivalent to linux `id`?

Comment: `id` does not shows the permissions of a user, it shows the `id`. "administrative rights" can be retrieved by (among others) `sudo`. then the output of `id` is meaningless in terms of finding out what the user _can_ do. just as a sidenote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run the following script:

```
NET SESSION >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    ECHO Administrator PRIVILEGES Detected! 
) ELSE (
    ECHO NOT AN ADMIN!
)
```

By the way, you can start command prompt with administrative privileges:

1. click on windows icon
2. type `cmd` in the search bar
3. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or click on "yes" when the UAC message appears

Related question answered on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights

Comment: `SHIFT+CONTRL+ENTER` doesn't seem to work on win8.

Comment: @Pacerier Double check that you're doing from the _search_ feature after clicking the `Windows Start` button. (I can confirm this works in Win 8.1 and Win 10)

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this solution is that if UAC is enabled it will just give an access denied error even if you have admin privileges.  If you are trying to batch test for admin rights on the machine in general (determine the user is somehow and admin on the machine) then this is useless.

Comment: This is more of a comment then an actual answer to the author's question.